# School Systems Java Code: cannot transfer data from one class to another

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have been tasked to create a school system coding assignment in Java. 
Here are the project requirements:

> We need to maintain the courses are taken and their respective grades; add a course with the grade, print all courses taken and the average grade. Assume that a student takes no more than 30 courses for the entire program. For teachers, we need to maintain the courses taught currently and are able to add or remove a course taught. Assume that a teacher teaches not more than 5 courses concurrently.

I am new to Java.

Here's my code:

**Main Class**

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

interface getTheName {

    String getName();
    String getRole();

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Information sys = new Information();
        Sensei sys1 = new Sensei();
        Trainee sys2 = new Trainee();
        Courses sys3 = new Courses();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Alan's Dojo begin the process for building your own ninja school!");
        while (true) {
            try {

                System.out.println("[1] Add Trainee");
                System.out.println("[2] Add Sensei");
                System.out.println("[3] Add course");
                System.out.println("[4] assign teacher");
                System.out.println("[5] Enroll Trainee");
                System.out.println("[6] Show courses");
                System.out.println("[7] Show Trainees");
                System.out.println("[8] Show Senseis");
                System.out.println("[9] Show all Ninjas");
                System.out.println("[10] Add marks");
                System.out.println("[11] Show marks");
                System.out.println("[12] exit program");
                int menu = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();

                int senseiID, traineeID, courseID, mark;
                switch (menu) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Enter trainee name: ");
                        sys.addTrainee(sc.nextLine());
                        //sys2.addTrainee(sc.nextLine());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Enter sensei name: ");
                        //sys.addSensei(sc.nextLine());
                        sys.addSensei(sc.nextLine());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Enter course name : ");
                        sys.addCourses(sc.nextLine());
                        //sys3.addCourses(sc.nextLine());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Enter sensei id : ");
                        senseiID = sc.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter course id : ");
                        courseID = sc.nextInt();
                        //sys.teachCourse(senseiID, courseID);

                        sys1.teachCourse(senseiID, courseID);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Enter trainee id : ");
                        traineeID = sc.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter course id : ");
                        courseID = sc.nextInt();
                        //sys.enrollTrainee(traineeID, courseID);
                        sys2.enrollTrainee(traineeID, courseID);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //sys.showCourses();
                        sys3.showCourses();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        //sys.showTrainees();
                        sys2.showTrainees();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        //sys.showSenseis();
                        sys1.showSenseis();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        sys.showNames();
                        break;
                    case 10:
                         System.out.println("Enter course id : ");
                         courseID = sc.nextInt();
                         System.out.println("Enter trainee id : ");
                         traineeID = sc.nextInt();
                         System.out.println("Enter mark : ");
                         mark = sc.nextInt();
                         sys.markTrainee(courseID, traineeID, mark);
                         break;
                    case 11:
                         System.out.println("Enter trainee id : ");
                         traineeID = sc.nextInt();
                         System.out.println("Enter course id : ");
                         courseID = sc.nextInt();
                         sys.showMarks(traineeID, courseID);
                         break;
                    case 12:
                         System.out.println("Please come back to Alan's Dojo soon!");
                         return;
                    default:
                        sc.nextLine();
                }
                sc.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                sc.nextLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

***Information Class***

```
package com.company;

public class Information {

    public getTheName allNames[];
    public int n_name;
    public Trainee allTrainees[];
    public int n_trainee;
    public Sensei allSenseis[];
    public Courses allCourses[];
    public int n_sensei;
    public int n_course;
    public int allMarks[];
    public int n_mark;
    public int mark;


    public Information()
    {
        allNames = new getTheName[30];
        allTrainees = new Trainee[30];
        allCourses = new Courses[30];
        allSenseis = new Sensei[5];
        allMarks = new int[100];
        n_course = 0;
        n_name = 0;
        n_sensei = 0;
        n_trainee = 0;
        n_mark = 0;
    }
    public void addTrainee(String name)
    {
        allTrainees[n_trainee++] = new Trainee(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allTrainees[n_trainee-1];
    }
    public void addSensei(String name)
    {
        allSenseis[n_sensei++] = new Sensei(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allSenseis[n_trainee-1];
    }
    public void addCourses(String name)
    {
        allCourses[n_course++] = new Courses(name);

    }


    public void teachCourse(int senseiID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].setSensei(allSenseis[senseiID]);
    }

    public void enrollTrainee(int traineeID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTrainee(allTrainees[traineeID]);
    }

    public void markTrainee(int courseID,int traineeID,int mark)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTraineeMark(allTrainees[traineeID]);
        this.mark = mark;
    }


    public void showCourses()
    {
        System.out.println("Course list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_course; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Course id" + i + " :" + allCourses[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public void showTrainees()
    {
        System.out.println("Trainees list:");
        for(int i = 0; i <n_trainee; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Trainees id" + i + " :" + allTrainees[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public void showSenseis()
    {
        System.out.println("Sensei list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_sensei; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sensei id" + i + " :" + allSenseis[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public void showNames()
    {
        System.out.println("Name list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_name; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(allNames[i].getRole() + ":" + allNames[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public void showMarks(int traineeID, int courseID)
    {
        System.out.println("Marks:");

        System.out.println(allCourses[courseID].getName() + " " + allTrainees[traineeID].getName() + " " + mark);
    }
}
```

***Ninja Class***

```
package com.company;

public class Ninja implements getTheName{

    public getTheName allNames[];
    public int n_name;
    public Trainee allTrainees[];
    public int n_trainee;
    public Sensei allSenseis[];
    public Courses allCourses[];
    public int n_sensei;
    public int n_course;
    public int allMarks[];
    public int n_mark;
    public int mark;

    public int id;
    protected  String name;

    public Ninja(String p_name) {
        name=p_name;
    }

    public Ninja() {
        allNames = new getTheName[30];
        allTrainees = new Trainee[30];
        allCourses = new Courses[30];
        allSenseis = new Sensei[5];
        allMarks = new int[100];
        n_course = 0;
        n_name = 0;
        n_sensei = 0;
        n_trainee = 0;
        n_mark = 0;
    }




    public void addTrainee(String name)
    {
        allTrainees[n_trainee++] = new Trainee(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allTrainees[n_trainee-1];
    }
    public void addSensei(String name)
    {
        allSenseis[n_sensei++] = new Sensei(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allSenseis[n_trainee-1];
    }
    public void addCourses(String name)
    {
        allCourses[n_course++] = new Courses(name);

    }


    public void teachCourse(int senseiID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].setSensei(allSenseis[senseiID]);
    }

    public void enrollTrainee(int traineeID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTrainee(allTrainees[traineeID]);
    }

    public void markTrainee(int courseID,int traineeID,int mark)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTraineeMark(allTrainees[traineeID]);
        this.mark = mark;
    }


    public void showCourses()
    {
        System.out.println("Course list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_course; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Course id" + i + " :" + allCourses[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public void showTrainees()
    {
        System.out.println("Trainees list:");
        for(int i = 0; i <n_trainee; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Trainees id" + i + " :" + allTrainees[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public void showSenseis()
    {
        System.out.println("Sensei list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_sensei; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sensei id" + i + " :" + allSenseis[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public void showNames()
    {
        System.out.println("Name list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_name; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(allNames[i].getRole() + ":" + allNames[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public void showMarks(int traineeID, int courseID)
    {
        System.out.println("Marks:");

        System.out.println(allCourses[courseID].getName() + " " + allTrainees[traineeID].getName() + " " + mark);
    }





    public  String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
public String getRole() {
    return null;
}

    //public  void setName(String p_name){name=p_name;}
    //public  String get_role(){return"Ninja";}
}
```

***Sensei Class***

```
package com.company;

public class Sensei extends Ninja implements getTheName{

    public getTheName allNames[];
    public int n_name;
    public Trainee allTrainees[];
    public int n_trainee;
    public Sensei allSenseis[];
    public Courses allCourses[];
    public int n_sensei;
    public int n_course;
    public int allMarks[];
    public int n_mark;


    public Sensei() {
        super();
        allNames = new getTheName[30];
        allTrainees = new Trainee[30];
        allCourses = new Courses[30];
        allSenseis = new Sensei[5];
        allMarks = new int[100];
        n_course = 0;
        n_name = 0;
        n_sensei = 0;
        n_trainee = 0;
        n_mark = 0;
    }


    public  String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void addSensei(String name)
    {
        allSenseis[n_sensei++] = new Sensei(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allSenseis[n_trainee-1];
    }


    public void teachCourse(int senseiID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].setSensei(allSenseis[senseiID]);
    }

    public void showSenseis()
    {
        System.out.println("Sensei list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_sensei; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Sensei id" + i + " :" + allSenseis[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public  String getRole() {
        return"Sensei";
    }

    public Sensei(String p_name) {
        super(p_name);
    }
}
```

***Trainee Class***

```
package com.company;

public class Trainee extends Ninja implements getTheName{

    public getTheName allNames[];
    public int n_name;
    public Trainee allTrainees[];
    public int n_trainee;
    public Sensei allSenseis[];
    public Courses allCourses[];
    public int n_sensei;
    public int n_course;
    public int allMarks[];
    public int n_mark;
    public int mark;

    public Trainee() {
        super();
        allNames = new getTheName[30];
        allTrainees = new Trainee[30];
        allCourses = new Courses[30];

        allMarks = new int[100];
        n_course = 0;
        n_name = 0;

        n_trainee = 0;
        n_mark = 0;


        //listTrainees = new Trainee[30];
    }

    public void addTrainee(String name)
    {
        allTrainees[n_trainee++] = new Trainee(name);
        allNames[n_name++] = allTrainees[n_trainee-1];
    }



    public void enrollTrainee(int traineeID,int courseID)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTrainee(allTrainees[traineeID]);
    }

    public void markTrainee(int courseID,int traineeID,int mark)
    {
        allCourses[courseID].addTraineeMark(allTrainees[traineeID]);
        this.mark = mark;
    }




    public void showTrainees()
    {
        System.out.println("Trainees list:");
        for(int i = 0; i <n_trainee; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Trainees id" + i + " :" + allTrainees[i].getName());
        }
    }

    public void showNames()
    {
        System.out.println("Name list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_name; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(allNames[i].getRole() + ":" + allNames[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public void showMarks(int traineeID, int courseID)
    {
        System.out.println("Marks:");
        System.out.println(allCourses[courseID].getName() + " " + allTrainees[traineeID].getName() + " " + mark);
    }

    public Trainee(String p_name) {
        super(p_name);
    }
}
```

***Courses Class***

```
package com.company;

public class Courses {

    public getTheName allNames[];
    public int n_name;
    public Trainee allTrainees[];
    public int n_trainee;
    public Sensei allSenseis[];
    public Courses allCourses[];
    public int n_sensei;
    public int n_course;
    public int allMarks[];
    public int n_mark;
    public int mark;

    private String name;
    public Sensei SenseiAssigned;
    public Trainee listTrainees[];
    public int n_student;

    public Courses(String p_name) {


        name = p_name;
        listTrainees = new Trainee[10000];
        n_student = 0;
    }

    public Courses() {
        allNames = new getTheName[50];
        allTrainees = new Trainee[30];
        allCourses = new Courses[50];
        allSenseis = new Sensei[5];
        allMarks = new int[100];
        n_course = 0;
        n_name = 0;
        n_sensei = 0;
        n_trainee = 0;
        n_mark = 0;
    }

    public void addCourses(String name)
    {
        allCourses[n_course++] = new Courses(name);

    }


    public void showCourses()
    {
        System.out.println("Course list:");
        for(int i = 0; i<n_course; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Course id" + i + " :" + allCourses[i].getName());
        }
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    // public  void setName(String p_name){name=p_name;}
    public void setSensei(Sensei prof) {
        SenseiAssigned = prof;
    }

    public void addTrainee(Trainee t) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_student; ++i) {
            if (listTrainees[i] == t)
                return;
        }
        listTrainees[n_student++] = t;
    }

    public void addTraineeMark(Trainee t) {
        listTrainees[n_student++] = t;
    }

}
```

### Problem

So the problem that I am currently having is that when I try and print either the names of the courses, senseis or trainees it won't print properly. This can be fixed if I move the "add senseis or trainees or Courses methods to their respective places in their own classes but then the printing of the mark of the trainee stops working.

### Edit

Output:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/btsFQPCiHP9NgeVq5

So I need the program to the list of trainees, senseis and the courses too. Along with the marking system to stay intact.

Comment: I didn't understood your problem. Can you show some sample output.

Comment: Please share sample inputs, expected output, and actual output. "it won't print properly" doesn't tell the reader any of this critical information.

Comment: added images of the output

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your Main class so that it would execute properly, and to use methods to minimize the amount of code to debug and understand.

I renamed your interface to more align with Java guidelines.

Here are the changes I made.

1. I reworked your `main` method so that it would exit when the user selected 12.
2. I moved the menu into a method, `getMenuSelection`, and added error checking.
3. I created two methods, `inputInteger` and `inputText`, to allow the user to input an integer and text, respectively.  I added error checking to the `inputInteger` method.
4. I got rid of all of the Scanner `nextInt` method calls.  You should just use the `nextLine` method.  It makes console input a whole lot easier to understand, and more importantly, to debug.

I wish I could show you one of your model classes, but I have a few questions before I could continue.

1. Where do the sensiID, courseID, and traineeID come from?  Do you create them, because you never ask the user to input them when the model rows are created?  How is the user supposed to know what these ids are?

Here's the code for your Main class.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

interface NameRole {
    String getName();
    String getRole();
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Alan's Dojo begin the process for building your own ninja school!");
        int menu = getMenuSelection(sc);
        while (menu != 12) {
            processMenuOption(sc, menu);
            menu = getMenuSelection(sc);
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    private static int getMenuSelection(Scanner sc) {
        int menu = -1;
        while (menu < 0) {
            System.out.println("[1] Add Trainee");
            System.out.println("[2] Add Sensei");
            System.out.println("[3] Add course");
            System.out.println("[4] Assign teacher");
            System.out.println("[5] Enroll Trainee");
            System.out.println("[6] Show courses");
            System.out.println("[7] Show Trainees");
            System.out.println("[8] Show Senseis");
            System.out.println("[9] Show all Ninjas");
            System.out.println("[10] Add marks");
            System.out.println("[11] Show marks");
            System.out.println("[12] Exit program");

            String input = sc.nextLine().trim();
            try {
                menu = Integer.valueOf(input);
                if (menu < 1 || menu > 12) {
                    System.err.println("The menu options must be a number from 1 to 12");
                    menu = -1;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("The menu option must be a number");
                menu = -1;
            }
        }
        return menu;
    }

    private static void processMenuOption(Scanner sc, int menu) {
        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            String name = inputText(sc, "Enter trainee name: ");
            break;
        case 2:
            name = inputText(sc, "Enter sensei name: ");
            break;
        case 3:
            name = inputText(sc, "Enter course name : ");
            break;
        case 4:
            int sensiID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter sensei id : ");
            int courseID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter course id : ");
            break;
        case 5:
            int traineeID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter trainee id : ");
            courseID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter course id : ");
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 8:
            break;
        case 9:
            break;
        case 10:
            courseID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter course id : ");
            traineeID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter trainee id : ");
            int mark = inputInteger(sc, "Enter mark : ");
            break;
        case 11:
            traineeID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter trainee id : ");
            courseID = inputInteger(sc, "Enter course id : ");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("Please come back to Alan's Dojo soon!");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private static int inputInteger(Scanner sc, String question) {
        int answer = -1;
        while (answer < 0) {
            System.out.print(question);
            String input = sc.nextLine().trim();
            try {
                answer = Integer.valueOf(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("You must type a number");
                answer = -1;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static String inputText(Scanner sc, String question) {
        System.out.print(question);
        return sc.nextLine().trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: The IDs are created as a new Sensei, Trainee or course is added, to see the IDs  of the different things, for example: when you select "Show Trainees" it prints out the IDs of each trainee that you have inputted

Comment: @Raygos Ok, how are the IDs created?  Are they a sequence (0, 1, 2, etc.) or are they created in some other manner?

Comment: yes, they are a sequence, for example, the first name of a trainee inputted would be "Id = 0"